# Azure boards - area set in Team configuration doesn't appear in Project configuration

Tags: azure-devops, configuration, area

In my Azure Boards project:

I have a team that need to see the whole project. For this team, in Team configuration > Areas I have set it to the whole project path including sub-areas.
When I go in Project configuration > Areas, the team does not appear in the list.

I don't have a problem with the other teams that only see some sub-areas, this is only happening with the main area (the root one).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Within project settings, go to the area paths of the Project Configuration, hover over the ... for the relevant area path and select security. You can then add permissions as required.

Project Settings --> Project Configuration --> Areas --> Ellipsis for relevant path (...) --> Security

Answer (score 0):

Team Name does not always equal Area Path, if you create a team and do not automatically create an Area Path with the same name as the team you will not see one that matches the team name.  Project Configuration > Areas you should see the name of the Team Project (root), this is not necessarily the same name as your Team you have created.

Wes

Comment: Hi, sorry, but what you say does not correspond to my question.